# Why is an ellipsis preferred to a variadic template when called with no arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, sfinae

I'm using the following SFINAE pattern to evaluate a predicate on a variadic type list:

```
#include <type_traits>

void f(int = 0);  // for example

template<typename... T,
    typename = decltype(f(std::declval<T>()...))>
std::true_type check(T &&...);
std::false_type check(...);

template<typename... T> using Predicate = decltype(check(std::declval<T>()...));

static_assert(!Predicate<int, int>::value, "!!");
static_assert( Predicate<int>::value, "!!");
static_assert( Predicate<>::value, "!!");  // fails

int main() {
}
```

To my surprise, the ellipsis overload is selected when `check` is called with an empty argument list, so `Predicate<>` is `std::false_type` even when the SFINAE-expression is valid!

Shouldn't variadic function templates always be preferred to ellipsis functions?

Are there any workarounds?

Comment: I think that depends on this mysterious part >> *"some SFINAE expression involving T..."* I believe this part rejects the overload when `T...` expands to empty set. You need to reveal the mystery.

Comment: Could you write the actual code? Or a code that produces this issue?

Comment: Interesting corner case. What is the use of it?

Comment: Is this simply a case of preferring non-template functions to templates when both are viable overload candidates and equally good matches?

Comment: @Casey I guess you're probably right; would you like to put that as an answer (quoting the standard if possible)?

Comment: @Casey Exactly what I thought. Ellipsis is typically ranked low because of the *ellipsis conversion sequence* which isn't applied here since there are no arguments.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When `T...` is empty, the compiler performs overload resolution to determine which of

```
std::true_type check(); // instantiated from the function template
std::false_type check(...);
```

is the best viable candidate, as described in [over.match.best] 13.3.3/1 (quoting N3936):

> Define ICSi(F) as follows:
>
> - if F is a static member function, ICS1 (F) is defined such that ICS1 (F) is neither better nor worse than ICS1 (G) for any function G, and, symmetrically, ICS1 (G) is neither better nor worse than ICS1 (F)132; otherwise,
> - let ICSi(F) denote the implicit conversion sequence that converts the i-th argument in the list to the type of the i-th parameter of viable function F. 13.3.3.1 defines the implicit conversion sequences and 13.3.3.2 defines what it means for one implicit conversion sequence to be a better conversion sequence or worse conversion sequence than another.
>
> Given these definitions, a viable function F1 is defined to be a better function than another viable function F2 if for all arguments i, ICSi(F1) is not a worse conversion sequence than ICSi(F2), and then
>
> - for some argument j, ICSj(F1) is a better conversion sequence than ICSj(F2), or, if not that,
> - the context is an initialization by user-defined conversion (see 8.5, 13.3.1.5, and 13.3.1.6) and the standard conversion sequence from the return type of F1 to the destination type (i.e., the type of the entity being initialized) is a better conversion sequence than the standard conversion sequence from the return type of F2 to the destination type. [ *Example:*
>
>   ```
>   struct A {
>     A();
>     operator int();
>     operator double();
>   } a;
>   int i = a; // a.operator int() followed by no conversion
>   // is better than a.operator double() followed by
>   // a conversion to int
>   float x = a; // ambiguous: both possibilities require conversions,
>   // and neither is better than the other
>   ```
>
>   —*end example* ] or, if not that,
> - the context is an initialization by conversion function for direct reference binding (13.3.1.6) of a reference to function type, the return type of F1 is the same kind of reference (i.e. lvalue or rvalue) as the reference being initialized, and the return type of F2 is not [ *Example:*
>
>   ```
>   template <class T> struct A {
>     operator T&(); // #1
>     operator T&&(); // #2
>   };
>   typedef int Fn();
>   A<Fn> a;
>   Fn& lf = a; // calls #1
>   Fn&& rf = a; // calls #2
>   ```
>
>   —*end example* ] or, if not that,
> - F1 is not a function template specialization and F2 is a function template specialization, or, if not that,
> - F1 and F2 are function template specializations, and the function template for F1 is more specialized than the template for F2 according to the partial ordering rules described in 14.5.6.2.

In this case, the conversion sequences for both candidates are empty since there are no arguments. The second to last bullet is the deciding factor:

> - F1 is not a function template specialization and F2 is a function template specialization, or, if not that,

hence the non-template `std::false_type check(...);` is preferred.

---

My preferred workaround - obviously there are many - would be to make both candidates templates and discriminate via the ellipsis conversion [over.ics.ellipsis] 13.3.3.1.3/1:

> An ellipsis conversion sequence occurs when an argument in a function call is matched with the ellipsis parameter specification of the function called (see 5.2.2).

by giving the "preferred" template declaration an extraneous parameter that is a clearly better match, since any other conversion sequence will be preferred to an ellipsis conversion per [over.ics.rank] 13.3.3.2/2:

> When comparing the basic forms of implicit conversion sequences (as defined in 13.3.3.1)
>
> - a standard conversion sequence (13.3.3.1.1) is a better conversion sequence than a user-defined conversion sequence or an ellipsis conversion sequence, and
> - a user-defined conversion sequence (13.3.3.1.2) is a better conversion sequence than an ellipsis conversion sequence (13.3.3.1.3).

[Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77bf9b05e3ce89fa):

```
template<typename... T,
    typename = decltype(f(std::declval<T>()...))>
std::true_type check(int);
template<typename...>
std::false_type check(...);

template<typename... T> using Predicate = decltype(check<T...>(0));
```

Comment: Probably way more standard quote than necessary, but I prefer complete references and this is a *big* paragraph.

Comment: Great explanation, thanks - and a much better way of writing `Predicate`.

Comment: The 2nd template check function (the one with ellipses), doesn't have to be ellipses function. `template<typename...>
std::false_type check(float);` works fine as well.

Comment: @BЈовић True - any viable signature with a conversion sequence worse than the identity sequence will result in the other overload being selected. I prefer the ellipsis conversion to make it painfully obvious, and it's become almost idiomatic in C++ to use the ellipsis for discriminating overloads in a type trait.

Answer (score 4):

That is surprising to me too.

One workaround could be to pass an `int` (e.g `0`) as first argument to `check()` and force the compiler to *try* the template version *first*:

```
template<typename... T, typename = decltype(f(std::declval<T>()...))>
std::true_type check(int &&, T &&...); //ADDED `int &&` as the first parameter type

std::false_type check(...);

template<typename... T> using Predicate = decltype(check(0, std::declval<T>()...));
```

Note that the temporary created out of `0` would try to bind to `int&&` **first** (and that is very crucial here), then if the value-sfinae fails, then it would try the second overload.

- [Demo @ Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1803d5fe673d6c68)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, that works - I'll probably use this workaround.  The `int const &&` in the ellipsis overload is unnecessary, though.

Comment: @ecatmur: Ohh. Yes. Removed it.

Comment: The `&&` on the `int` is unnecessary btw.

Comment: @dyp: Yes. But I wrote it because of my habit (and thats not bad here); in case if you've lots of overloads, then conversion sequence `int&& -> int const&& -> int const volatile && -> int const & -> long && -> etc` forces the compiler to *try* overloads in *particular* order!